# How to get particular key and value from json object to store in database?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

```
{
    "purchaseorder": {
        "Meta": [{
            "InterchangeControlNumber": ["000004010"],
            "GroupControlNumber": ["833"],
            "DocumentControlNumber": ["5952"],
            "InterchangeSenderID": ["009483355"],
            "InterchangeReceiverID": ["076627454"],
            "GroupSenderID": ["009483355"],
            "GroupReceiverID": ["076627454"]
        }],
        "header": [{
            "address": [{
                "home": [{
                    "hno": ["134/123"],
                    "contact": ["898944343"],
                    "pin": ["272272"],
                    "district": ["telangana"]
                }],
                "office": [{
                    "hno": ["456/789"],
                    "contact": ["440838272"],
                    "pin": ["55833"],
                    "district": ["delhi"]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

I have JSON data like the above.

I want to store it in database as meta, home and office as table names, with the respective keys as column and value as cell data.

How do I the data from the JSON in node.js or JavaScript?

The JSON data can be any thing. I can pass the name of required table to be created, it should be automated.

Comment: You will need to provide more info. Is the data always structured that way? What have you tried already?

Comment: Have you tried parsing the JSON with `JSON.parse` and lookup the properties in the resulting object?

Comment: What type of database? Relational? Document store?

Comment: Also, do you want separate tables called 'meta', 'home' and 'office', or one table holding all of the information?

Comment: the database is sql server and the data  is always structured . if i want to to store in a single table how to store it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't know too much about SQL Server, but hopefully this should get you going along the right lines on the Javascript side of things.

**Convert JSON to Javascript Object**

You can turn the JSON data into a key-value accessible object, and then access `meta`, `home` and `office`, as follows:

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsonData);

var meta = data.purchaseorder.Meta[0];
var home = data.purchaseorder.header[0].address[0].home[0];
var office = data.purchaseorder.header[0].address[0].office[0];
```

Then to pull out specific values you can do, for example:

```
var homeContact = home.contact; // Will return "898944343".
```

**Retrieve Column Names**

If, as you say, the data can change, one way that you could derive column names is this:

```
var metaColumns = Object.keys(meta);
var homeColumns = Object.keys(home);
var officeColumns = Object.keys(office);
```

Note: Javascript objects do not necessarily preserve property ordering, so these columns may not be in the same order as they appear in the data.

**Create Table and Insert Data**

You can put together corresponding arrays of column names and values for this purpose:

```
var allColumns = metaColumns + homeColumns + officeColumns;
var allValues = [];

for (let col of metaColumns) {
    allValues.push(meta[col]);
}

for (let col of homeColumns) {
    allValues.push(home[col]);
}

for (let col of officeColumns) {
    allValues.push(office[col]);
}
```

From here you can build your `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` SQL statements, with the column names and values as parameters, using a suitable `node.js` library for SQL Server, such as [this](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql).

Be aware that if this data comes from an untrusted source you should make sure to *sanitise* it properly to prevent the possibility of SQL injection.

Comment: thanks but here we are hard coding the xpath like var meta = data.purchaseorder.Meta[0];
var home = data.purchaseorder.header[0].address[0].home[0];
var office = data.purchaseorder.header[0].address[0].office[0]; can we automate where user will only pass the object name like   setdata(home,office);

Comment: Are you saying that the structure of the data can change to the point where the information on, e.g. home or office, could appear at any level in the document?

Comment: yes. it can be dynamic json data.  actually i am getting this json from npm xmltojs. where i am providing path of xml and the node js genrate this complex json .  so i want to provide facility where user can pass the tag name of xml and it the related data filter from json object and stored in database automatically. means it will create table automatically and store all the record.        https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js this is the npm